# Why django admin page does not have any css included?

Tags: python, django

My problem is that when I set the DEBUG in settings.py file to False and add the localhost to ALLOWED_HOSTS, then my admin page gets empty of css. 
I want to solve the issue and know why it happens

I have tried running the collectstatic command I don't get any error however, the problem still exists

```
`DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
                 'localhost',
                 '127.0.0.1'
]`
```

Comment: Show your `settings.py` and elaborate what does `it does not work` mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place this code in your settings.py, then you have the `collectstatic`

update Try this way for your project.:

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ....urls......
    ) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

in your settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
REPOSITORY_ROOT = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

ROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')  # specify static root

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(REPOSITORY_ROOT, 'media/')
```

In your shell

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```